# CURL PHP POST interferes with JSON

Tags: php, json, http, post, curl

I currently have an API script that returns JSON. It has worked up until I tried to add in a `curl php POST` script before it. The curl script is working on it's own, and it is also working in the API script. However the JSON code is not being returned.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this approach below?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The `curl` script works 100% on its own. 
      Said script is also working inside the below, it's just that the `JSON` does not return.

```
$name   = "foo";
$age    = "bar";

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://www.example.com';

$fields = array(
            'name' => urlencode($name),
            'age' => urlencode($age)
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);    
return json_encode(
    array(
        "status" => 1,
        "message" => "Success!",
        "request" => 10
    )
);
```

Comment: _"However the JSON code is not being returned."_ - then enable error reporting, since when the `return` isn't being called your code clearly fails before that.

Comment: Maybe you want to `echo` the JSON instead?

Comment: it fails at the foreach point, but the curl script works. The values are POSTED successfully

Comment: Maybe this is because $field_string is not already declared and you want to extend it with .= operator. Try to add $field_string = ''; befor your foreach (i think this will throw a php-warning)

Comment: You do not need to encode your post data yourself. curl can accept an array and do the encoding for you, e.g. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields)` will work, if you remove the urlencode stuff when you build $fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following use `echo` and also use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` if not the output would be transferred directly to the page instead of `$result`

```
$name = "foo";
$age = "bar";
$url = 'http://.../a.php';
$fields = array('name' => urlencode($name),'age' => urlencode($age));
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header('Content-type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode(array("status" => 1,"message" => "Success!","request" => 10));
```

Comment: Thank you @Baba, That solved the problem of the JSON not being returned. However, the curl POST has stopped working as a result. Any ideas? i.e. is the `foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');` required? Thank you

Comment: I have tested that curl script on it's own and it does not do as I require. The form it needs to take a `HTTP POST` only. Could this be the issue?

Comment: What from are you talking about .. put it in paste bin let me see .... am working blind here

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out. The second part was an API issue. Thanks a million for the help!